# Laptop does not power on when battery < 10%

Tags: laptop, battery, power

I have HP 245G7 notebook with Windows 10 2004. Its low battery has 3 levels or indicators.

- Low battery level at 15% (Green Exclamation mark appears on battery icon)
- Low battery at 10% (Yellow exclamation mark appears on battery icon)
- Critical Low at 5% (at which the laptop hibernates)

I have an observation. When battery falls just below 10% say it’s at 9.4% and I shutdown the laptop, now when I try to power it on, it just does not. Nothing happens when I press the power button. The moment I plug in adapter and start charging, then laptop can power on upon pressing the button.
So when battery is < 10% laptop does not power on when on battery.

There still is say 9.4% juice in battery, still it does not power on!
No such observation when battery > 10%.
Is this behavior by design or some fault somewhere?

Obviously contacting HP was my first choice, but despite several days gone they are just not responsive.
HP assistant software does not show any issue with battery as such. Laptop is otherwise working normally.

Other details – BIOS is latest. All Windows 10 drivers including battery/ACPI/Firmware etc are latest. Battery is not user serviceable/ accessible. There’s no pinhole on back panel or anywhere to simulate battery removal and reinsertion.
I have already tried to manually calibrate it by full charge and full discharge and again full charge. I checked the user manual, there’s no such mention of any such behavior being normal.

Answer (score 1):

It takes much more power to start a laptop than to keep it running. So if it is running, and is now at 10% or a bit less, it will drop to 5% and then suspend or hibernate - whatever you set it for.

But it is unlikely to start at (say) 9+% as it may drop to 5% while starting and then suspend or hibernate from an inopportune point.

So (a) it makes sense that your laptop will not start at 10% and (b) my two laptops (Lenovo) will not start at 10%,  Battery needs to be at least at 15% charge for mine to start.

I think you are saying yours will start at 15% as well.

Comment: My machine is Lenovo and it will start if at least 10% but starts faster at 15% or more.